# Give user some feedback when they land on custom login page

Tags: login

I have a drop down menu which contains my custom login box...

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="<?php echo bloginfo('url') ?>/wp-login.php" method="post">
    <p class="login-username">
        <input placeholder="email address" type="text" style="text-align:right;" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="" size="20" />
    </p>
    <p class="login-password">
        <input placeholder="password" type="password" style="text-align:right;" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20" />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" value="Login" /><input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />
</form>
```

This works great, what happens if somebody either enters nothing in the boxes and presses submit or enters incorrect detail is they are taken to a custom login page at www.mydomain.com/login

This is all good but what I need to do is give the user some indication of why they have landed on this page, a message box saying 'Incorrect details please try again'

Anyone any ideas how I would go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of options at your disposal.

Two of which could be;

1) Stop the user from being re-directed to /login and use jQuery to alert the user that their login information is incorrect on the page in which the details were entered.

2) You could have them re-directed to the /login page and edit the /wp-login.php file to add a block of HTML (which will tell the user they entered their details incorrectly) and style it with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a hidden field in your custom login form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom-login" value="1" />
```

And hook into the wp-login form (head, footer or the form itself):

```
add_action( 'login_head', 'failed_login_message', 10, 0 ); // display message at top of page
// add_action( 'login_footer', 'failed_login_message', 10, 0 ); // display at bottom of page
// add_action( ''login_form_login', 'failed_login_message', 10, 0 ); // display message WITHIN the form

function failed_login_message() {
  // bail if the user does not come from the custom login form
  if ( ! isset( $_POST['custom-login'] ) || true != $_POST['custom-login'] )
    return false;

  echo '<p class="error">Something went wrong. Your login data wasn\'t correct. Try again.</p>';

  return true;
}
```